# How to update AlertDialog content using showDialog(id)

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

i want to have in my application an alertdialog, that has its message updated everytime it is showed. 
This is because the dialog box value depends on some values on the application.

Now i tried to use the showDialog method:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
    showDialog(RESULT_DIALOG);
    return false;
}
```

But once the dialog is created, it doesn't change the message (i know that if the dialog is created, it use the started version).

My onCreateDialog method code is:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(int dialogId) {
    AlertDialog dialog;
    switch(dialogId) {
    case RESULT_DIALOG:
        // do the work to define the pause Dialog
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(localTv.getText())
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });                                 
        dialog = builder.create();
        break;
    default:
        dialog = null;
    }
    return dialog;
}
```

There is a way to update the content of the AlertDialog. 
Actually i create a new dialog box every time the onTouch event is called. But i'm not sure that it is the cleanest way to solve that problem.

Any idea? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use onPrepareDialog method:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog ( int id, Dialog dialog ) {
    switch ( id ) {
        case RESULT_DIALOG:
            AlertDialog alertDialog = ( AlertDialog ) dialog;
            alertDialog.setMessage( localTv.getText() );
            break;
    }
    super.onPrepareDialog( id, dialog );
}
```

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html :

> Before the dialog is displayed, Android also calls the optional
>   callback method onPrepareDialog(int, Dialog). Define this method if
>   you want to change any properties of the dialog each time it is
>   opened. This method is called every time a dialog is opened, whereas
>   onCreateDialog(int) is only called the very first time a dialog is
>   opened. If you don't define onPrepareDialog(), then the dialog will
>   remain the same as it was the previous time it was opened. This method
>   is also passed the dialog's ID, along with the Dialog object you
>   created in onCreateDialog().

Answer (score 2):

You can always change the dialog using onPrepareDialog or you can remove the dialog (so it will always pass through onCreateDialog) setting the onDismiss (dialog.setOnDismiss) to remove the dialog id (removeDialog(id)).